# Java: Special type, bad operand type for binary operator

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors

I'm working on trees in java. I am currently working on retrieve and insert methods.
Here are the methods:

```
public void insert(E item) {


    if(item <= node.item){
        if(node.left == null){
            node.left = new TreeNode<E>(item);
        }
        else{
            insert(node.left.item);
        }
    }
    else{
        if(node.right == null){
            node.right = new TreeNode<E>(item);
        }
        else{
            insert(node.right.item);
        }
    }

    root.item = item;
}

public E retrieve(E item) {

    if(item == node.item){
        return item;
    }
    else if(item <= node.item){
        if(node.left == null){
            return null;
        }
        else{
            return retrieve(node.left.item);
        }
    } else{
        if(node.right == null){
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return retrieve(node.right.item);
        }
    }

}
```

In the code above, the if statements:

```
if(item <= node.item)
```

...Are giving me the following errors:

```
java: bad operand types for binary operator '<='
first type:  E
second type: E
```

I am bit confused because when I switch up the operand with compareTo() it let's me know that the result is boolean but we are expecting int. I'm not too sure how to compare them anymore; or rather with what to compare them.
SOS!

Thank you,
T

Comment: Java has no operator overloading. `E` needs to be `Comparable` (or you need a `Comparator<E>`). How have you defined `E`?

Comment: `item` is of type `E`... what is `E`?

Comment: I am not too sure as my teacher lacks giving information with assignments. I'm guessing it's just a type that our teacher decided on:

public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> extends BinaryTree<E>

Answer (score 1):

Give your teacher a heart-attack, let's fix his generic type first. This

```
public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<E>> extends BinaryTree<E>
```

should be

```
public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends BinaryTree<E>
```

And you can use [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) to perform the comparison. That is,

```
if(item <= node.item){
```

should be

```
if (item.compareTo(node.item) <= 0)
```

And so on, using `item.compareTo` instead of `<`, `==` or `>`.